# KMeans vectorized implementation updating cluster centroids. Numpy pro

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'mn implementing kmeans in python. In a single iteration i have computed the center labels for each 150 points:

```
label = 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 4, 0, 4,
       6, 7, 7, 1, 7, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3, 7, 0, 1, 3, 7,
       5, 1, 4, 3, 0, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=int64)
```

and initial 8 centers:

```
centers =
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
       [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2]])
```

X is the iris data X.shape=(150, 4):

```
X =
array(  [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3],
   [5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2],
   [5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4],
   [4.6, 3.6, 1. , 0.2],
   [5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5],
   [4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2],
   [5. , 3. , 1.6, 0.2],
   [5. , 3.4, 1.6, 0.4],
   [5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2],
   [5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2],
   [4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2],
   [4.8, 3.1, 1.6, 0.2],
   [5.4, 3.4, 1.5, 0.4],
            ...
```

Now I want to based on current center labels to update centers. That means iterate unique values in label. Then extract all corresponding points in X, calculate center based on all extracted points. Finally update centers. For example, in first iteration, extract all elements in X with label 0. Then calculate center(mean of each dimension). Then update centers[0] to new center. And so on for label 1, 2...

That's one iteration in original kmeans algorithm. My problem is how can i write this step in a numpy vectorized way instead of looping over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update centers

You can use [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [computation along an axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html) to only explicitly iterate over the clusters instead of over every single data point.

```
K = 8
for k in range(K):
    centers[k] = X[label==k].mean(axis=0)
```

### Update labels

This can also be done by iterating over all clusters:

```
distances = np.empty(shape=(X.shape[0], K))
for k in range(K):
    distances[:, k] = np.sqrt(np.sum((X - centers[k])**2, axis=1))
labels = distances.argmin(axis=1)
```

But it can also be done without an explicit loop by exploiting that matrix multiplication is the pairwise dot product.

```
squared_distances = np.sum(centers**2, axis=1) + (np.sum(X**2, axis=1) - 2*centers @ X.T).T
squared_distances[np.isclose(squared_distances, 0)] = 0  # self-distance can become slightly negative with this method (floating point precision problem)
distances = np.sqrt(squared_distances)
labels = distances.argmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. The way you update centers are what Im looking for. It's very neat. Tho still have  one loop. My way updating labels is similar to yours.

Comment: I don't think there is a more efficient way to do this. And with a relatively low K, the loop should not impact the runtime too much.